# How to trigger bloc listener with the same state multiple time?

Tags: flutter, bloc

My bloc returns NetworkErrorState if there is no internet connection. And it will show a widget with a 'Try Again' button. When I press the button when there is still no internet connection, it will return the same state and the same message and Failure. How will I trigger the bloc listener again with the same state?

Bloc State:

```
 class NetworkErrorState extends MyBlocState {
      final String message;
      final Failure failure;
    
      NetworkErrorState ({this.failure, this.message});
      @override
      List<Object> get props => [failure, message];
    }
```

Exception:

```
class ServerException implements Exception {
  final String message;

  ServerException({this.message});
}
```

Failure:

```
abstract class Failure extends Equatable {
  final List properties = const <dynamic>[];
  Failure([properties]);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => properties;
}

class ServerFailure extends Failure {
  final String message;

  ServerFailure({this.message});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

Comment: Probably adding the setState into listener would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, by design. But I see two very viable options. I would probably go with number 1...

1. emit a different state between your two NetworkErrorStates. Pressing the "try again button" (the function that is called) could first emit e.g. RetryingConnectionState. Your ui could display something nice then?

Or...

2. Another way to work around that is to pass an extra variable with the state that changes, so that it won't be recognized as the same state (make sure that variable is taken into consideration by equatable props). It could e.g. be reconnect attempt number or a timestamp when last retry was made.

Comment: Personally, I'll go with your first solution. That's the approach I tend to use when using BLoC

Comment: Yeah absolutely. Actually the first doesn't imply that you cannot have second as well. The UI maybe want to present how many connection attempts have been made :)

Comment: I've not had a need to keep track of connection attempts, but when I do, your approach definitely makes sense :)